# deleting number and colon in text file\

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'am a newbie in Python and i want to make a simple code that will erase a numbers and colon from my txt file.

Example :
**00:00:01:05 00:00:03:12** so I thought it was very interesting
**00:00:03:12 00:00:06:15** when we did the videos that most of the
**00:00:06:15 00:00:09:09** line of business users minds are around
**00:00:09:09 00:00:12:04** data rate about data analytics and you

I want to remove the bolded part.

Anyone has any idea for a code ?
Thank you guys in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

Use `regex` and I am assuming you know how to read a `txt` file already.

```
import re
new_string = re.sub('\\d+:\\d+:\\d+:\\d+', '', your_string_here)
```